# CMD/FTP to create folder using to today date & connect ftp download into created folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I'm new to this cmd/FTP command. I would like to create a new folder at my local directory using today's date and connect to FTP to download the specific file to the newly created folder. If I manually type in command one by one at cmd, it has no issue. But when I use a batch file to run, my command stopped at FTP.

```
setlocal enableextensions
set name=%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4"_"job%
mkdir C:\%name%
cd C:\%name%
ftp
open 192.168.31.93
*user*
*password*
binary
cd *directory*
mget -i *.*
```

I did try to separate my command to two batches; 
1. folder creation
2. FTP download but the file downloaded didn't go into the folder I created. the downloaded file went to C:\Document & Settings.

main batch file

```
@echo off
call rename.bat
ftp -i -s:ftp.txt
```

rename.bat

```
setlocal enableextensions
set name=%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"_job"
mkdir c:\%name%
cd c:\%name%
```

ftp.txt

```
open 192.168.31.93
*user*
*password*
binary
cd *directory*
mget *.*
close
```

Another method I try is using '!' when in FTP environment, then create a folder then exit back to FTP environment. This method again doesn't work with the batch file. Please help

Comment: *"I did try to separate my command to two batches"* - So show that in your question. You have a single script there, which can newer work (and does not as your know yourself). ---  *"file downloaded didn't go into the folder I created"* - So where did it go to? --- Try `cd /D C:\%name%`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i have editted my main post. The downloaded file went to c:\documents & setting. i think the reason is because i *cd c:\%name%* at 1st batch. But my problem is i couldnt *cd c:\%name%* at ftp environment because %name% was not recognized in ftp environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that with command extensions enabled, the working directory set by a child batch file is lost, then the batch file exits.

I'm not sure how to solve it, but you actually do not need the `rename.bat` file to be a separate file. This *"main batch file"* should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set name=%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"_job"
mkdir c:\%name%
cd /d c:\%name%
ftp -i "-s:%~dp0\ftp.txt"
```

Also note the `/d` added to `cd`. Without that your batch will not work when started from another drive. You also have to use `%~dp0` to refer to the batch file folder for the `ftp.txt`. As at the time `ftp` is called, you have changed to the target directory.

---

You possibly do not even need the command extensions to be enabled. So simply removing the `setlocal enableextensions` might solve the problem too. Though you still need the `%~dp0` and `/d`.

Comment: Don't you think doing `set "name=%date:~-10,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~-4,4%_job"`  would be better than `set name=%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%"_job"` ?

Comment: Well, definitely. But I've copied that part from OP's code. And it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok, no problem, just an observation :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I shall test it asap and update here

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to post this, although similar to the answer given, there are a couple of differences.

- It creates the text file, then deletes it, *(this keeps everything more portable)*.
- I have corrected your directory name, *(because of a typo)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Name=%DATE%"
Set "Name=%Name:~-10,2%-%Name:~-7,2%-%Name:~-4%_job"
MD "C:\%Name%" 2>Nul
CD /D "C:\%Name%" || Exit /B
(   Echo open 192.168.31.93
    Echo *user*
    Echo *password*
    Echo binary
    Echo cd *directory*
    Echo mget *.*
    Echo close
)>"ftp.txt"
FTP -i -s:ftp.txt
Del "ftp.txt" 2>Nul
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I will test it out and update