# Windows FTP command-line client does not download all files with mget *

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I use batch file to FTP into remote and try to download all files in the specific directory using `mget *.*`. But during transfer, it does not download all files.

This is my script:

```
open 192.168.31.93
*user*
*password*
binary
cd *directory*
mget *.*
close
```

Output of the script:

```
ftp> Connected to 192.168.31.95.

open 192.168.31.95
220 i4hp FTP server (Version 1.7.212.2 Tue Apr 21 12:14:46 GMT 1998) ready.
User (192.168.31.95:(none)): ---> 
USER ifour
331 Password required for ifour.
---> 
PASS ifour22
230 User ifour logged in.
ftp> Interactive mode Off .

ftp> prompt
---> binary
TYPE I
200 Type set to I.
ftp> ---> cd /console/i4/work/job/hd/bin
CWD /console/i4/work/job/hd/bin
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> ---> ls
TYPE A
---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,208
200 PORT command successful.
---> NLST
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.
file.dbv

errlog

file.db

para.job

job.exp

job.exp.b

.SF.pickupdb.wind

.SF.pickupdb.ptype

.SF.dbnichijor

.SF.dbnichijor2

.SF.db.JOBD.Main

lockfile

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.PP.revc

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.pconect.revc

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.ftype.revc

.SF.db.JOBD.Edit

.SF.db.JOBD.Edit.PP.revc

.SF.db.JOBD.Edit.pconect.revc

.SF.db.JOBD.Edit.ftype.revc

.SF.db.queued.Daemon

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:0

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:1

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:2

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:3

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:4

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:5

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:6

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:7

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:8

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:9

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.Pi.fffb0000:10

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.fffb09

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.fffb0b

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.fffb0a

.SF.db.JOBD.Main.fffb08

... (lots of files omitted)

226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 34913 bytes received in 0.25Seconds 139.65Kbytes/sec.

---> TYPE I
ftp> ---> mget *.*
TYPE A
---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,209
---> NLST *.*
---> TYPE I
200 Type set to I.
---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,210
200 PORT command successful.
---> RETR file.db
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file.db (134437620 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 134437620 bytes received in 120.22Seconds 1118.28Kbytes/sec.

---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,213
200 PORT command successful.
---> RETR file.dbv
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file.dbv (42766240 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 42766240 bytes received in 38.36Seconds 1114.89Kbytes/sec.

---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,221
200 PORT command successful.
---> RETR job.exp
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for job.exp (14752535 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 14752535 bytes received in 13.25Seconds 1113.40Kbytes/sec.

---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,222
200 PORT command successful.
---> RETR job.exp.b
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for job.exp.b (12997544 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 12997544 bytes received in 11.78Seconds 1103.26Kbytes/sec.

---> PORT 192,168,31,93,16,223
200 PORT command successful.
---> RETR para.job
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for para.job (76751 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 76751 bytes received in 0.22Seconds 350.46Kbytes/sec.

ftp> ---> disconnect
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
ftp> quit
```

Comment: Show us your complete `ftp` script. Show us equivalent FileZilla log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i added another image 'filezilla' on my main post together with the coding.

Comment: Log file, not panel screenshot.

Comment: And we need at least some placeholder name for the directory in your script, so that we can compare it to the FileZilla log.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl hi, i have add in screenshot of my coding under 'ftp_screenshot' and attach filezilla log through dropbox

Comment: There's no `-i` switch in `mget`. There are no switches in `ftp` at all.

Comment: Do not post code as an image.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, i do have put '-i'. May refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057742/cmd-ftp-to-create-folder-using-to-today-date-connect-ftp-download-into-created/55060991#55060991) for full coding. the screenshot is for the directory path which requested from previous comment.

Comment: I mean that `mget` command in `ftp` **does not have any `-i` switch**. So this won't work: `mget -i *.*` --- There's no `mget -i` in the link you have posted.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sorry for that. My mistake. I do put 'mget -i' but still encounter same issue. File not exist but downloaded with 0kb

Comment: *"I do put 'mget -i'"* --- ???? There's **NO** `-i` switch in `mget`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i'm sorry. I don't understand what u mean. I have updated my [coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057742/cmd-ftp-to-create-folder-using-to-today-date-connect-ftp-download-into-created) with 'mget -i'

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Do u mean that in ftp, should not use '-i'?

Comment: But why? **Why are you adding `-i` to `mget`?** What do you think it does? Or what do you want it to do? **`mget` does not have any `-i` switch.** It does not have any switches at all. **`mget -i` will try to download file named `-i`, what will fail.** -- You keep posting links to other question, but there's no `mget -i` in any of the answers.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the reason i put '-i' is to stop the CMD for prompting on every file. Is this the wrong way? I will try using 'prompt'

Comment: That's what `ftp -i` does, as all the examples show.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl [without -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmjrm.jpg) here is the result without '-i'. Only large file will be downloaded and 1kb file is ignore. Anyway to download everything in the folder? Advice are deeply appreciated.

Comment: If you do `ls` or `dir`, can you see the file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, 'dir' i can see all the files. here is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amn0n.jpg)

Comment: Show us a complete verbose output (a copy, not a photo) of `ftp` output with both `ls` (not `dir`) and `mget *.*`. Add `-d` switch to `ftp`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl how can i save a copy of the output?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i try to use 'echo ls>>output.txt' it print out my command rather than output result

Comment: `ftp -d -i -s:yourscript.txt > output.txt`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl here is the output file [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9n0fd4re6xblr3/cmdftp.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Did you try `mget *`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, using `mget *`and `mget *.*` will get same number of file

Comment: So I assume that `dir *` lists only those few files, not all, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i use `ls`, total file is 1000+ files (refer to this: [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9n0fd4re6xblr3/cmdftp.txt?dl=0) ). But downloaded files is only 5 files.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl was it possible that the files unable to download as it was used by system?

Comment: I'm asking what does `dir *` show, not what does `ls` show -- And no, I do not think the problem is with the file being in use.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, correct. The `dir *` somehow only listed those few files been downloaded. Any idea why it is so?

Comment: What about `dir -a *`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl `dir -a *` show `Type A`. It doesn't list out any files inside the directory.

Comment: Did you make it working?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i try to get my administrator to install the winscp but it was rejected. So i couldnt test the winscp

Comment: You do not need to install WinSCP. There's [portable package](https://winscp.net/eng/downloads.php#stable_portablezip). – Just extract the ZIP along with your WinSCP script.

Answer (score 0):

`mget <mask>` command in Windows command-line `ftp` client internally uses `NLST <mask>` FTP protocol command. Your FTP server does not return the "dot" files for `NLST *` (probably because it considers them hidden).

You will have to use another FTP client, which does not leave file mask resolution to the server.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), this will work:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@192.168.31.93/" ^
    "cd /remote/directory" ^
    "mget *" ^
    "exit"
```

There's even a [guide for converting `ftp` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*